# Enterprise Rent-A-Car at Kahului: Is there a shuttle to the 40 Hana location?

Tags: airport-transfer, car-rentals, hawaii

When searching for **Enterprise Rent-A-Car**, I get 2 locations:

1. 40 Hana HWY Kahului, HI 96732-2105
2. Kahului ARPT Kahului, HI 96732

I know the second one is the official airport location, but it is not clear to me if the first location (40 Hana) can be reached easily from the airport as well.
Does anybody know if there is a shuttle bus running from the airport to the 40 Hana Rent-A-Car location?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is about $10 taxi ride to 40 Hana HWY location.

consider than $20 in total (cover both ways) and than consider if the savings are worth it.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer : No, they do not.

Longer answer : The airport and 40 Hana Highway locations are separate locations - one serves the airport, and the other primarily serves the pier.  The airport has a shuttle that runs from the airport to the airport location (which is actually a few hundred yards away from the airport).  The 40 Hana location has a shuttle that runs to the pier.

In general when rental companies have two locations as close as this they will normally allow pick-up from one location and drop-off at another without charging a one-way rate - although renting from the airport location may be a little more expensive due to airport fees.